# How to connect to AR Drone using nodejs on laptop

Tags: node.js, ar.drone

I am just getting started using NodeJS and the ar drone package to program a Parrot AR Drone. Most of the tutorials I have searched through jump straight to code with which to control the drone without saying anything about connecting, so I'm going into it a bit blind.

I connected to the drone's wifi network with my laptop. But when I tried executing a basic repl.js:

```
var arDrone = require('ar-drone');
var client  = arDrone.createClient();
client.createRepl();
```

I got an `ENOTCONN` error, which, from what I can tell, means I am not connected to the drone properly. Is there anything I need to do to connect to the drone, other than be connected to the wifi network? Is there something else that the `ENOTCONN` error could mean?

Answer (score 0):

NO, if you are connected with the wifi-spot created from the drone you should be ok.
Double check your connection and if you have a valid IP assigned. Are you running that code on a virtual machine? In that case you should check the network options of your virtual machine player.